# How to OneHotEncode X and y values for an ANN?

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I am working with a dataset of mushroom features to determine whether a mushroom is poisonous or not. The model I built works, but I'm trying to use OneHotEncoder as a way to practice encoding. I know we have to instantiate the OneHotENcoder class, and fit_transform the dataframe. From there, we establish the X and y values and built the model like usual. What I'm having trouble with is fitting the X and y values. In the code below, I get an error with the variable X: "drop not found."

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ohe = OneHotEncoder()

df = ohe.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,:])

ohe.categories_

X = df.drop('class', axis=1)
y = df['class']

X = ohe.fit_transform(X)

y = one.fit_transform(y)
```

I expect the above code to encode both the Xs and ys, which I want to use to train test split and built a small ANN. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One hot encoder returns a numpy array and not a dataframe.

You should first drop target column and then apply one hot encoder.

```
exempt_cols = set(['class'])
categorical_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in exempt_cols]
X = df[categorical_cols]
X = ohe.fit_transform(X)
```